Fabric registering an item twice?
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to register ID ResourceKey[minecraft:item / biomelist:warped_beehive] at different raw IDs (1256, 1271)! If you're trying to override an item, use .set(), not .register()!

Here is my code:

Honestly doesn't matter what I change it makes minecraft crash and gives me that error,most times with warped but sometimes with acacia, nothing changed so far, it just doesn't open and constantly crashes under the same error

Welcome on StackOverflow. Prefer copy/paste instead of showing picture of your code. For your issue, did you tried to comment the warped_beehive to check if the mangrove_beehive would do the same issue ?
